# Not upload the jquery.min.js and mathquill.js file?

Tags: angular

Angular project is given me the below error. But, all my file paths are correct?!

```
1=>Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4203/assets/css/perfectscroll.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2=> Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the `angular.cli.json` and the `package.json` file?

Comment: Sorry but we can not post the complete angular.cli.json  and the package.json file

Comment: I just need the part of `styiles` and `scripts` in your angular.cli.json. Is that possible to you? Ususally you import all the css and the js there

Comment: "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/angular2-perfect-scrollbar/dist/lib/perfect-scrollbar.component.css",
        "styles.css"


      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"

      ],

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Dont put more infos into comments, always update your question instead!

Comment: Plus: please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: try looking here: https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170

Comment: Can you actually show the output of `http://localhost:4203/assets/css/perfectscroll.css`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that styles and scripts shouldn't be loaded like this. Note that you have a file .angular-cli.json or angular.json (if you are using @angular/cli, if not I'd recommend you to). And there you can add 3rd party scripts and styles with links to them, so when the project gets built these files will be already included.

In case you don't use @angular/cli. You still have your index.html file, where you can add styles with a `<link>` and probably scripts may be added there too.

It really depends on which tool you are using to build an angular app. Comment below or please add some more details to your question about what you are using(cli, angular, etc) with specified versions.

*Update*

then you have to pass a link into your `.angular-cli.json` file in styles and scripts sections (arrays), path should be staring from `src` folder :

`"styles": [ "/assets/css/perfectscroll.css", "../node_modules/my-lib/styles/style.css" ]`

and same for scripts:

`"scripts": [ "/assets/css/perfectscroll.js", "../node_modules/my-lib/script.js" ]`

Comment: my cli version 1.7.4

Comment: and we using angular version 4.4.6